# How to give images to right of the the html Table

Tags: html, css, django, web, alignment

I have made a Django website and want to display my result like at the top there is a small form.Under that in the left there is a table and i want to add to images and another column in the right if the table.
I have made a design to explain better -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7BsO.jpg)

Now I have written the code for the form 1 and table. I will write the backend code too .I want to know how will I write html for the images and form 2 as they are in right of the table.As soon as write any html code it comes under the table. Anyone can help to add pics and form2 on the right of the table.

my html code till now is-

```
*{% extends 'login/basic.html' %}
{% block title %}Approval of count{% endblock title %}
{% block body %}

<!-- <div class="container my-5 px-2"> -->
<form action="/approval" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <!-- <div class="container" >
            <div class="form-group mx-5 my-3">

                <div class="form-group mx-5 my-3">
                    <label class="my-3" for="date">Date</label>
                    <input type="date" id="date" name="date">
                </div>

                <label class="form-group mx-5 my-3" for="servers">Choose the server from - {{serverLst}}</label>
                <div class="form-group mx-5 my-3">
                    <select name="serverName" id="forserver" size="4" multiple>
                        {% for server in serverLst %}
                        <option value="{{server}}">{{server}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mx-5 my-3">Submit</button>
            </div>

        </div> -->

    <div class="row g-2">
        <div class="col-md">
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="floatingInputGrid" name="date">
                <label for="floatingInputGrid">Shift Date</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md">
            <div class="form-floating">
                <select name="serverName" class="form-select" id="floatingSelectGrid">
                    <option selected>Server Name</option>
                    {% for server in serverLst %}
                    <option value="{{server}}">{{server}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
                <label for="floatingSelectGrid">Select your server</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md">
            <div class="form-floating">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mx-5 my-2" id="floatingInputGrid">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<!-- tables  -->

<table class="table" style="width:25%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">User name</th>
            <th scope="col">Starting</th>
            <th scope="col">Ending</th>
            <th scope="col">Bonus</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<!-- </div> -->
{% endblock %}
```

- 

any suggestion to make my html code better will be very helpful also and please ignore if there are any html errors

Answer (score 0):

try using css properties ,  namely position:absolute or position:fixed. 'https://sbgsdjango.herokuapp.com/English'
, this website is a demo for you , no need

Comment: Thank you very much bro.Can't tell you how much you helped me.From your comment I found a same thing -https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-float-three-div-side-by-side-using-css/                                                                                                                                            Now I am doing == <style>
    .table{
        float:left; 
        width: 25%;
    }
    .abraka{
        float:right;
    }
</style>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).